# Struggling with .htaccess (Godaddy Linux Hosting)

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, redirect, web-development-server

I would really appreciate your help with the below. I have been both googling and testing code via trial an error, I believe that I'm slowly figuring things out but I would appreciate the fast track assistance in both the result and my learning development.

I currently have a website hosted on a shared resource on a apache Linux server through GoDaddy. I am trying to achieve the following;-

1) Redirect non www traffic to www.

2) Remove the .html file extension and add a trailing slash on the web address.

I currently have the code below, the 301 www. redirect is working and the trailing slash is also working. However I am getting 404 errors on the subpages ie www.swiftcomm.co.uk/contact/;-

How do I go about resolving this issue with the code?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
# Redirect to domain with www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Same for HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Ensure all directory URLs have a trailing slash.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/[^\/]*\.[^\/]+$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
# Same for HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/[^\/]*\.[^\/]+$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Much of the code you're using seems to be somewhat unnecessary. The www rule for HTTPS can be combined into one. And you don't need to do an HTTPS check for trailing slashes. However, my question is this: You want to remove the html extension and force trailing slashes. Do the html files still exist, and do you want to rewrite to them? So requesting `/contact/` would serve `/contact.html`. (Your intentions here are not very clear, so I need to ask.)

Comment: Mike, Thanks for responding. I am ultimately trying to enforce that if someone were to enter swiftcomm.co.uk/contact it would redirect to www.swiftcomm.co.uk/contact/ this would be served by the contact.html page in the root directory. I hope this makes more sense?

Comment: It does, will answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code - it can replace your entire file. The comments explain what each ruleset does.

```bash
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Force www. prefix - http/https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Remove .html extension suffix from URI only if it matches an existing file.
# Add trailing slash simultaneously.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s\/(.+)\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=302,L]

# Force trailing slash if it has'nt been forced already.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(.+[^/])$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=302,L]

# Rewrite non-existing files to their .html counterparts.
# If the .html file does not exist, Apache will gracefully degrade to a 404.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Mike, Thanks again for your time and assistance. I have replaced the code with everything in my .htaccess file. I have checked the site and homepage loads correctly, the sub pages are having some issues.  www.swiftcomm.co.uk/services load but without any of the external content (Java, CSS, Images). I performed an inspect element and noticed that i'm getting quite a few ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Comment: The ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE seem to be due to the fact that the links are now pointing to incorrect locations for example http://www.swiftcomm.co.uk/services/img/menu-bg.jpg/ Failed to load resource: this may be due to the img folder being in the route directory so http://www.swiftcomm.co.uk/img/menu-bg.jpg/

Comment: You need to reference your assets relative to the root of the site. So just add a `/` before each `src`.